# Localized iOS app layout

Tags: ios, localization, internationalization, autolayout

We build an iOS app and an Android app.  In our Android app, most everything is mirrored when using a Right-to-left language.  I'm unclear what the expectation is for our iOS app.

When localizing an app for a right-to-left language, what should change?  Specifically, should the left button and the right button in the navigation bar be reversed?  Should the "back" button be in the right side?  I'm confused on what to expect, to know if I made a mistake in setting out the project.  What about the order of buttons in the toolbars and tabbars?

Comment: Hey, i want to do same, as you have mention it. i want to update all views after language change from english to arabic. thank you for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The way it changes is just the text. The layout of the UI doesn't need to change. Because right to left cultures read .... right to left. However they don't need things to be switches around, not so?